# Difference between oncreate and onRestoreInstanceState method in activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Guys I am stuck in a problem with these two methods:-

When I change the orientation of device and set the text in edit text after retriving the text from bundle,it does't work.But the same code is working in onrestoreStoreInstante method.

Please have a look at my code:-

```
public class LifeCycleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

EditText user;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    user=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_user);

    if(savedInstanceState!=null){

        String s =savedInstanceState.get("Key").toString();
        user=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_user);
        user.setText(savedInstanceState.get("Key").toString());         

        Toast.makeText(this, s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

     Toast.makeText(this, "onSaveInstanceState",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        outState.putString("Key", "Deepak");
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    //String s =savedInstanceState.get("Key").toString();
    //user.setText(s);
     Toast.makeText(this, "onRestoreInstanceState",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    Toast.makeText(this, "onStart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    Toast.makeText(this, "onResume",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    Toast.makeText(this, "onPause",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    Toast.makeText(this, "onStop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
      Toast.makeText(this, "onDEstroy",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRestart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     startActivity(new Intent(LifeCycleActivity.this,SecondActivity.class));
}
```

}

when I set the text in edit text in oncreate method after getting  the value from Bundle,it doesn't work.But the same code works in onRestoreInstanceState() method.

According to me , it should work for oncreate also as we can get the Bundle class object there.
Please help me to sort out this problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EditText` and most of other views have their own methods to save/restore their own data. So in general it's not necessary to save/restore them on your code.

You can see this here on the [Android TextView source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) (remember that EditText extends from TextView) on line 3546:

```
if (ss.text != null) {
    setText(ss.text);
}
```

so the reason you can't set it `onCreate` and can do it `onRestoreInstanceState` it's because during your activity `super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)` the activity calls the `EditText.onRestoreInstanceState` and the EditText restore it self to the previous value.

You can see it happening on the [Activity source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java) on line 940

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (mWindow != null) {
        Bundle windowState = savedInstanceState.getBundle(WINDOW_HIERARCHY_TAG);
        if (windowState != null) {
            mWindow.restoreHierarchyState(windowState);
        }
    }
}
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Overview**

- `onSaveInstanceState()` is used to put the data to bundle
- `onRestoreInstanceState()` is used to set the data available in
  bundle to your activity

---

**So do as follows:**

1. i Guess until the activity is created `onorientation` change the
   bundle is not available, that's way you are not able to retrieve it
   in `oncreate`
2. Let the activity create in `oncreate`
3. Then restore the instance in `onRestoreInstanceState`

***Hope this helps !***

Comment: I debug my application.I am getting bundle in oncreate aslo.So My question is why I am not able to set text in edit text in oncreate method while the same thing is done in onRestoreInstantstate..Then what is the use of bundle object in oncreate ??